# Why am I getting an exception Failure when trying to send an email using smtp?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public void sendit()
        {
            try
            {

                SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("out.bezeqint.net");

                // set smtp-client with basicAuthentication
                mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                mySmtpClient.Port = 110;
                mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
                   System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass");
                mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;

                // add from,to mailaddresses
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test@bezeqint.net", "TestFromName");
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("test@bezeqint.net", "TestToName1");
                MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

                // add ReplyTo
                MailAddress replyto = new MailAddress("test@bezeqint.net");
                myMail.ReplyToList.Add(replyto);

                // set subject and encoding
                myMail.Subject = "Test message";
                myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                // set body-message and encoding
                myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
                myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                // text or html
                myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
            }

            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException
                  ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The exception happen in the first catch.

```
"Failure sending mail."

StackTrace

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Emails\SendEmail.cs:line 150
```

Line 150 is

```
mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
```

The client bezeqint is pop3 at least for getting/downloading emails I'm using openpop. But to send emails I'm using smtp and getting the exception.

In top of form1

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

More info about the exception:

[System.Net.WebException] = {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

And StackTrace

```
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

And InnerException

InnerException = {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.115.187.185:110"}

Comment: what exception type?

Comment: 1. Please include the complete exception, this means stacktrace, the full type, and the full message. 2. You are losing your stack trace in your catch blocks, never do `throw ex;`, instead just write `throw;` and in your SmtpException catch also do `throw` as ApplicationException does not add any benefit OR include the original exception in your new exception (see the constructor overload) so you do not lose your stack trace.

Comment: I also see that: My outgoing server requires connection (SSL). And also require authentication.

Comment: Looks like you need to verify your connection parameters. It might require a different port? or some other different setting.

Comment: Solved it. Sorry for the mess. The problem was the port number. Not 100 but 25. To download/get emails port 110 to send emails port 25.